# what I should vs. which I should

Tags: relative-pronouns

> A: I have three exams this week. I don't know
>   ***what/ which(one)*** I should study first.
>
> B: Making a study schedule might help.

Which is the right choice? and why is it?

Comment: You might find [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/which-vs-what-whats-the-difference-and-when-should-you-use-one-or-the-ot) helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are limited to the words as supplied, then **which** is incorrect. However, a simple addition makes it grammatical:

> I have three exams. I don't know which [of them] to study **for**.

We don't "study an exam". We study *for* an exam.

> I have three exams. I don't know what [thing] to study.

**what** is an empty room. There, it can hold *anything that can be studied*. Unlike **which**, **what** does not refer back to an antecedent.

> Here are three kittens. Which do you like best?
>
> Here are three kittens. Which of them do you like best?

The two sentences above are equivalent in meaning.

> Here are three kittens. I know what they like to play with: yarn.

Here, **what** is an unspecified *thing*, and when it is modified by "they like to play with", **what** refers to *thing-they-like-to-play-with*.

> The kittens knocked a vase over. I didn't know what to say to them.

There, **what** is also a *thing*, broadly understood. When it is modified by "to say", it refers to *thing-that-can-be-said*.

As you can see from these examples, **what** does not refer back to an earlier noun.

Comment: Can I say 'I don't know for which exam I should study first.'?

Answer (score 0):

"Which." You are choosing from a set of three options; it is not an indefinite open set that you are picking from **if** the answer to the question is one of the three.
If it were an indefinite open set (e.g. the answer of what to study could be any possible point or sub-topic), "what" would sound more natural.

In either case, you will be understood here.

Answer (score -2):

"Which" is the best, because there are limited options.